# Profiling values for null and not null count on all attributes

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

I have a table which which has e.g 3 attributes in below table , using hive / sql
i have a use-case which consist of over 50 attributes which require me to do profiling on this values  nullcount,notnull etc etc, as per current use-case, am not able to do any data transformation using pyspark/plsql which im hitting a roadblock

For demo purposes, lets say i have 3 attributes which only need notnull count for 2 tables, Malaysia & Thailand

```
describe malaysia

ColumnName |  Datatype
custid     |  String
productid  |  String
addressid  |  String

describe thailand

ColumnName |  Datatype
custid     |  String
productid  |  String
addressid  |  String
```

as per my current approach , this is how i do it ,

```
select COUNT(CASE WHEN custid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "NullCount",
COUNT(CASE WHEN productid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "NullCount",
COUNT(CASE WHEN addressid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "NullCount" 
from malaysia 
union
select COUNT(CASE WHEN custid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "NullCount",
COUNT(CASE WHEN productid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "NullCount",
COUNT(CASE WHEN addressid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "NullCount" 
from thailand
```

knowing i have over 50 attributes per-table, the query will be long and i dont feel its the right approach as maintance is going to be messy and hard. I was wondering if there is any better approach of producing the same result.

Comment: Fix your data model!  That is the fundamental problem.  You should not be storing the data in many tables, just as multiple rows in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data model!  You should have all the data in a *single* table with a column for `country`.  Then you could simply do:

```
select country,
       count(custid) as custid_not_null,
       count(productid) as productid_not_null,
       count(addressid) as addressid_not_null
from all_countries
group by country ;
```

Note that `count(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values of the expression.  The `case` expression is totally superfluous.

Absent that, you *could* create a view:

```
create view all_counties as
    select 'malaysia' as country, t.*
    from malaysia m
    union all
    select 'thailand' as country, t.*
    from thailand t
    union all
    . . .;
```

But I would advise you to put all the data in a single table.

Comment: I have remodal my data. however i have over 100 attributes in a single table which is partition by country, i can use group by clause but. I was wondering if there is any statment that enables me to select all attribute as a column instead of querying ' select as_of_date as columnname ... union select currency as colummane etc etc.

Comment: havin 100 attributes , instead of specifying one by one like the example u have given , count(custid) as custidnotnull.. count product id as productnotnull... , are we able query in one single line for all attributes to give null records ?

Comment: @FAves . . . Put all the data in one table!  Fix the data model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your sql a bit. Instead of count use sum. I added total count for better analysis. I do not have any easy method but you can put list of columns in XL and create a formula from that which will create this string automarically `SUM(CASE WHEN custid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Nullcustid"`.

```
select 
COUNT(*) "TotalCount",
SUM(CASE WHEN custid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "NullCust",
SUM(CASE WHEN productid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE  0 END) as "Nullprod",
SUM(CASE WHEN addressid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Nulladdress" 
from malaysia 
union
select 
COUNT(*) "TotalCount",
SUM(CASE WHEN custid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "NullCust",
SUM(CASE WHEN productid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE  0 END) as "Nullprod",
SUM(CASE WHEN addressid IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Nulladdress" 
from thailand
```